# TextFields unresponsive in Xcode8 / Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Is anyone else having a problem with unresponsive Texfields?

My login screen and forgot password screen used to work on swift2.3 and Xcode 7, but after upgrading they are inconsistent. Every time I load the new view-controller for forgot password the cursor in the textfield stops flashing and the keyboard also won't show up. Almost feels like a delegation error...

The app isn't crashing though and you can still exit from this VC back to login?

Also can't type any text into the textfield from my keyboard.

I am assuming the error is either an IDE bug OR some new swift3 syntax that I haven't picked up on yet.

If anyone has a definite answer for this or there is some code that needs to be updated please let me know.

PS. I am using the Spring cocoapod so maybe this is even a DesignableTextField error?

This is the pod for Spring:

> pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', branch: 'swift3'

Comment: It normally works in my case. I have not used "DesignableTextField" yet, But high possibility may be because of that too it not working. If you try with UITextField it will work as expected.

Comment: I tried Spring, Create two text field Username and Password using "DesignableTextField", And it work as expected they should be. Make sure you are using updated version of Spring code compatible to swift 3.0.

Comment: Make sure you are using this cocoa pod : pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift3'

Comment: I had this issue even not using Spring. But the issue disappeared when I launched the app directly from device/simulator instead of build and run in Xcode. So weird...

Comment: Issue still there when changed to standard UITextField.